# Wifi has odd behavior

Tags: wifi, networking, hp

I´m using a HP Stream 13 which has a Realtek RTL8723BE (or similar) wifi/bluetooth chip with elementary OS Loki 0.4.

Wifi is always working after reboot of system. Sometimes my network show great strengh, sometimes the signal is very low. It changes dramaticaly even when I´m at one spot. Sooner or later I´m still connected but no services nor sites will load.

I shut wifi down and turn it on again. Sometimes it works, sometimes Wifi won´t turn on again. To make it work again, I restart.

Other devices have no issue with my Wifi. I used Ubuntu 16.04 till yesterday. Under Ubuntu je Wifi worked fine. Sometimes i needed to restart networking after waking up my laptop from suspension, but that was just ocassionaly.

Any suggestions?
Thanks!
Pier

Answer (score 1):

The Realtek wireless cards have a sleep mode to save battery when you don't use the net conecction. The vendor has a poor support to Linux drivers,  so you can try to disable the sleep mode with the next trick.

Open a terminal and execute:

```
echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

Reboot your system. If it don't solved your problem, you can use some of the forked drivers like:

[lwfinger at github.com](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new)

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Do you use RTL8723be on Loki?

Comment: @efkan , try changing your antenna selection with:

`echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=2 fwlps=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf`

Comment: Thank you. But I had tried a lot of things. Unfortunately https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/issues/184

Comment: @efkan , can you share the output for the following command?

`lsmod | grep rtl`

Comment: ```rtl8723be              94208  0
btcoexist             180224  1 rtl8723be
rtl_pci                28672  1 rtl8723be
rtlwifi                77824  3 btcoexist,rtl_pci,rtl8723be
mac80211              737280  3 rtl_pci,rtlwifi,rtl8723be
cfg80211              565248  3 wl,mac80211,rtlwifi
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
bluetooth             520192  31 bnep,btbcm,btqca,btrtl,btusb,hci_uart,rfcomm,btintel
```

Comment: Ok, no rtl8xxxu driver. Have you disabled your secure boot mode? I've read about some driver problem with secure boot enabled.

Comment: Yes I have. Actually I have never switch to enabled the secure boot option. It seems disabled as default. Thank you anyway...

Answer (score 0):

I use this one with all Ubuntu based Distros and it has worked every time.
I tried it on Loki but couldn't manage to get it done. I don't know if it was because they removed the debi or something.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms linux-firmware
sudo reboot now
```

If you make it work I'm sure it'll help you, I'm currently using it on Linux Mint 18 and it Works absolutely PERFECTLY. BTW, if you manage to get it to work can you please tell me how? :D

Comment: There is no any `Xenial` package in the repo (https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/rtlwifi). Do you encounter with any issue these days?

Comment: There are some *Xenial* packages. Take a look at https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/rtlwifi?field.series_filter=xenial